# How to get Client's public ip address without using third party api in Blazor webassembly client side?

Tags: ip-address, blazor-webassembly

Currently I am using third party api to get client's ip-address in blazer webassembly client side. Is there any way to get the ip-address in blazor webassembly client side?

Comment: thanks for reply @JG222 how can we get information from ISP any idea?
without third party api i can not get public ip?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a way other than making an API request. The reason is that your public IP address is subject to change. Your ISP might assign you a different address and so there isn't any sense in keeping that stored on your local device. When you run `ipconfig` on your command line your computer hits your router and asks for it's private IP address on the network, and it's essentially the same for your public IP. So since your public IP address could change, it's best to just call a service like the one I mentioned. Is there a reason that you don't want to use an API?

Comment: okay understood thanks for sharing information @JG222.